# How to change From Name in Laravel Mail Notification

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-notification

This is the problem:

[image: This is the problem]

The name associated with the email shows up as "Example"

Comment: `->from('example@example.com', 'Awesome Name')`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In `config/mail.php`

set `from` property as:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'someemail@example.com', 'name' => 'Firstname Lastname']
```

Here, address should be the one that you want to display in from email and name should be the one what you want to display in from name.

P.S. This will be a default email setting for each email you send.

If you need to use the Name as a variable through code, you can also call the function from() as follows (copying from Brad Ahrens answer below which I think is good to mention here):

```
return $this
    ->from($address = 'noreply@example.com', $name = 'Sender name')
    ->subject('Here is my subject')
    ->view('emails.view');
```

Comment: Thank for replying, even though i have found it first then your comment..

Comment: Of course yes. But in the said comment you need to do this in each and every Mail::send() method wherever you use it. But in my case you don't need to do it. Thanks for accepting this answer.

Comment: if we configure like this, can we overwrite the from address as mentioned in the above comment?

Comment: Yes, you can. Please see answer below from @Haseena P A.

Comment: ->from('info@websitedomain.com', 'Website Name') worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

You can use

```
 Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

        $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
    });
```

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail

Answer (score 17):

In the case of google SMTP, the from address won't change even if you give this in the mail class.
This is due to google mail's policy, and not a Laravel issue.
Thought I will share it here.

Answer (score 16):

A better way would be to add the variable names and values in the `.env` file.

**Example:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_FROM_NAME="My Name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@example.com
```

Notice the last two lines. Those will correlate with the *from name* and *from email* fields within the Email that is sent.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who is using **Laravel 5.8** and landed on this question, give this a shot, it worked for me:

Within the build function of the mail itself (not the view, but the mail):

```
public function build()
{
    return $this
        ->from($address = 'noreply@example.com', $name = 'Sender name')
        ->subject('Here is my subject')
        ->view('emails.welcome');
}
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

- **If you want global 'from name' and 'from emai**l',
- **Create these 2 keys in .env file**
- **MAIL_FROM_NAME**="global from name"
- **MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS**=support@example.com

And remove 'from' on the controller. or PHP code if you declare manually.
now it access from name and from email.

`config\mail.php`

```
 'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'info@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'write name if not found in env'),
    ],
```

ON my controller.

```
$conUsBody = '';

        $conUsBody .= '<h2 class="text-center">Hello Admin,</h2>
                        <b><p> '.trim($request->name).' Want some assesment</p></b>
                        <p>Here are the details:</p>
                        <p>Name: '.trim($request->name).'</p>
                        <p>Email: '.trim($request->email).'</p>
                        <p>Subject: '.trim($request->subject).'</p>';

      $contactContent = array('contactusbody' =>  $conUsBody);

      Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.mail'], $contactContent,

      function($message) use ($mailData)
      {
        $message->to('my.personal.email@example.com', 'Admin')->subject($mailData['subject']);
        $message->attach($mailData['attachfilepath']);
      });
      return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }
```

My blade template.

```
<body>
{!! $contactusbody !!}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an error in your fragment of code. You have
`from(config('app.senders.info'), 'My Full Name')`
so config('app.senders.info') returns array.
Method from should have two arguments: first is string contains address and second is string with name of sender. So you should change this to
 `from(config('app.senders.info.address'), config('app.senders.info.name'))`